# precise control over water re-mineralization

Tags: water, water-hardness

I have been trying for, literally, decades, to get really good coffee.

I roasted for several years, and for two cups during that time, I reached absolute nirvana with coffee that tasted so good it literally changed my life. However, it was so hit and miss, I essentially gave up on it.

Now I'm desperately trying to be sure I'm doing the most that I can to do everything right to attempt to arrive at that taste with what I hope anyway, is recently roasted beans, though trying to locate a source of those, from a roaster that is willing to divulge the age of the roast (I am in a rural area, there is no "local" roaster I can form a relationship with) is proving difficult. Anyone who knows of such a mail order roaster, I would love to hear.

Starting with the basics, I am trying to get the water exactly right as per the SCAA recommendations. If I understand those correctly, it should be chemical free water, with a TDS level of around 150.

I purchased an ISpring RO filter system, with a re-mineralization filter. It does it's job, though the TDS at the outlet turns out to be around 30-40 range. So, being an engineer, I assumed I could put 5 remineralization filters in series, and "of course" I'd end up with 5 * 30, or 150 TDS.

Hah !

Not even close, with five such filters it didn't increase the TDS at all. I can almost see why when I think about it.

So my question is: How can I get re-mineralization up to 150 TDS with my RO water filter.

Note that I'm aware of packets of minerals you can buy to add to water. I'm really looking for a "machine" solution, i.e., totally hands off yet extremely precise every time, without any sort of intervention other than turning on a tap. If there's no other solution, maybe I could build an automated "doser" to dump minerals in as the system calls for water. Maybe such a thing already exists ?

Thanks all for your help, and patience reading my question.

Nate

Comment: Welcome to Coffee. Just a quick suggestion that may help get you answers. Stack Exchange sites are different from typical discussion forums. It's a Q&A model to build a knowledge base of focused questions and answers. The backstory detracts rather than helps here. You'll get a better response with a short, focused question limited to the essential information of a single issue.  If there's more than one question, post them as separate questions. Good luck on your quest.  :-)

Comment: Thanks fixer !!
You're absolutely right and thank you for reaching out to let me know.

As a software developer, I spend a lot of time on StackOverflow looking for answers, and when I hit the search terms just right, I get one that looks like it's going to be exactly what I'm looking for. Only to read some insane history and background the OP has to layout, and I'm thinking, AACH, get to the question !

Anyway, even in this answer I have a problem keeping it short !

Anyway, thanks again 
Nate